# Google maps waypoint coordinates for route

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I'm rather new to the Google Maps API. If I get a route back from Google maps, is it possible to get the coordinates for every 2 km of the route? So if the route is 7 km, I want to know the coordinates of 2 km, 4 km and 6 km.